# Keeping tab group at bottom always with new windows

Tags: windows, tabs, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Is it possible to keep a tab group at the bottom of an iOS app but open windows independent of those. Ideally I want 3 tabbed icons at the bottom which go back to 3 main pages but from the main page you can open 8 other pages.

Only way I can think about doing this is to create my own bar at the bottom which opens pages on their own.

Hope this makes sense!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open windows within the context of the tab group you need to open them as the child of one of the tabs using that tab's [open Method](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Tab-method-open).